# Aggregate no C# não retorna nada?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Fiz uma consulta direto no console que me retornou o que eu esperava, a consulta no mongo está assim.

```
db.AtividadeResultMongo.aggregate([{$unwind: "$LsVariaveisProcesso"},
    {$match: {
        IdAtividade : 913,
        IdEstadoInstanciaAtividade : 6,
        LsVariaveisProcesso : { $regex : /^idato/i }
    }},
    {$project: {
        LsVariaveisProcesso: 1
    }},
    {$group: { _id: "$LsVariaveisProcesso" }},
    {$count: "total"}])
```

quando executo me retorno ***total : 113*** que está correto, tem valores na base, porem no `C#` não retorna nada e preciso de ajuda para montar isso ai no c#, alguém pode me ajudar?

Tentei começar assim

```
var agg = ObterCollection("AtividadeResultMongo")
          .Aggregate()
          .Match(new BsonDocument { 
            { "IdAtividade", "913" }, 
            { "IdEstadoInstanciaAtividade", "6" } });

var teste = await agg.ToListAsync();
```

mas na variavel teste não tem nada, a conexão está correta com a base está correta, rodei um count e retornou valor

```
ObterCollection("AtividadeResultMongo")
       .AsQueryable()
       .Count()
```

Comment: Thiago a coleção `AtividadeResultMongo` você precisa fazer o que, tipo esqueça da parte console ?

Comment: Então dentro do meu LsVariaveisProcesso tenho um array de string, nele pode ter uma string assim "idAto:9999" que vem de outro sistema, eu só gravo, então o usuário me pediu para agrupar por um campo que ele vai informar no sistema dele, no caso ele vai querer totalizar documentos que tenham dentro desse array "idAto" porem pode existir mais de um documento com o mesmo idAto, então olhando a consulta ali, se eu tirar o group de LsVariaveisProcesso está retornando 580 itens, porque existem documentos com o mesmo idAto

Comment: com `Where` e contains se pode filtrar isso Thiago, já tentou ... o que é mais dificil é que não tem como reproduzir, mas, eu faço isso no mongodb facilmente com C#

Comment: Tipo: `ObterCollection("AtividadeResultMongo").where(x => x.IdAtividade == "913" && x.IdEstadoInstanciaAtividade == "6" && LsVariaveisProcesso.Contains("idato")).Sum()` já tentou?

Comment: Cheguei agora em casa e tentei rodar o que você passou, porem não encontrei .where no IMongoCollection, faltou algum using?
Coloquei o AsQueryable<T> antes porem não rolou o Sum pq só da certo com AsQueryable<int> 

Mesmo assim eu entendi sua ideia, mas onde vc está agrupando pelo idAto? tentei fazer um group com contains o MongoDB.Driver.Linq
falou que "Contains of type System.String is not supported in the expression tree {x}.Contains("idAto")"

Comment: Eu ja tinha tentado isso a tarde, estou o dia todo nisso, e não deu, sempre dava esse mesmo erro.

Por isso pedi para me ajudar a escrever o aggregate que fiz direto no mongo

Comment: Complicado dizer